# How to make speaker render silence output for 2 sec in ALSA (Advanced Linux Sound Architecture)

Tags: linux, alsa

I want make the audio speaker on a computer silence for 2 sec by writing 0's data to "default" device using [ALSA (Advanced Linux Sound Architecture)](https://www.alsa-project.org/). Below is code snippet.

```
int val
int size = 24000;
u_char *tmp_buffer = (u_char *)malloc(size);
memset(tmp_buffer,0,size);

if ((val = snd_pcm_writei(pcm_handle, tmp_buffer, size)) == -EPIPE)
{

    snd_pcm_prepare(pcm_handle);
}
else if (val < 0)
{
    qDebug()<<"ERROR. Can't write to PCM device " << snd_strerror(val);

}
free(tmp_buffer);
```

With the above code, it render as "chuck chuck .." noise not silence .

How to render silence output to speaker for 2 sec?

Comment: Wouldn't leaving the speaker off and playing nothing be quieter than trying to play what ends up being "white noise"? PS. If you're asking about programming specifically, https://stackoverflow.com is great

Comment: What are the sample format, rate, and channels?

Comment: @CL,Sample rate 48000, channel is 2 and format is S16_LE.

Answer (score 2):

With a sample rate of 48000 Hz, two seconds need 96000 frames, so that is the number you need to give to `snd_pcm_writei()`.

With four bytes per frame, the size of the temporary buffer must be 384000.

Comment: snd_pcm_writei(pcm_handle, tmp_buffer, 384000) for 2 sec this will render silence or noise to speaker...?

Comment: 384000 frames would be wrong.

Comment: I understand that temp buffer size should be 384000 (48000*2*2*2) but what should be number of frames for snd_pcm_writei?

Comment: The size of one frame is four bytes.

Comment: thanks I understood (384000 /4) is number of frames.(pcm_handle, tmp_buffer, 96000)